# Android Camera Use with Tabbed Navigation

Tags: android, camera, fragment

I'm using this tab navigation: https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsColors/index.html

From the Android Developers site.

However I am unable to use a camera in any simple way, as the onActivityResult is never called. Apparently it works fine for fragments but presumably because the SlidingTabsColors example uses nested fragments (I think?) with the SlidingTabsColorsFragment creating (?) new fragments like this:

```
Fragment createFragment() {
   return ContentFragment.newInstance(mTitle, mIndicatorColor, mDividerColor);
}
```

So my onActivityResult is never called. I have tried every variation of calling it that I could find suggested.

I've got some incredibly strung out code in the initial activity now that looks for the fragment and passes it the requestCode, resultCode and the data, all of which are off or null though (possibly another problem).

Is there a way I can have a smooth, tabbed navigation and be able to use the camera? I've not included any specific code as it's just the base code I mentioned, with a variety of attempts at simply calling a camera and saving an image. The camera opens and works fine, we just never get to onActivityResult. Is there perhaps another way to go about this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you try `Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)`?

Comment: Thanks, but yes. I've got it working, via a very excessive method passing down information from onActivityResult's in activities to fragments. The issue of the whole thing being so long and arduous is still a question though. I'm looking for an easier way to achieve the same results or get onActiviyResult returning within my fragment.

Comment: Are you overriding onActivityResult() in your fragment or in your Activity?

Comment: Attempting to simply overwrite it in my fragment does not work, but would be the ideal situation. I am overwriting it in the activity, then passing it back to my fragment by looking for a fragment that implements an empty interface class I made.